# From security perspective, what should I do when allowing users to upload files?

Tags: asp.net, xml, security, validation, file-upload

I allow the user to upload an `xml` file. From security perspective, what should I do? I want to prevent the user from uploading more than three times per day.  I am looking for any suggestions about the security issues.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the context of your question? What types of users (authenticated?) are you working with?  What kind of security concerns do you have?  Do you need to verify the XML files before they do something?  What have you tried?

Comment: yes authenticated users.

Comment: yeah , i need to verify the XML files .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Basic sanity check on file size
2. Avoid validating using DTD or XSD. If you must, be sure to read about ["XML bombs"](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/776.html). Also, XSDs may be downloaded from the internet. An attacker may input a XSD url that takes forever to load, leading to a DOS
3. Verify the XML based on your business rules, and DELETE it from the hard disk if it doesn't pass you verifications.
4. If you save the files on your server, make sure the directory doesn't have execute permissions
5. Its a good idea to rename the file to a random name, so even if the file is "abc.xml", it will be saved as abc-433fdsadf3234234.xml on the hard-disk.
6. Do NOT allow the user to download the file that he uploaded via an anonymous URL. If you can, prevent downloads of uploaded files. If you cannot, use a throw-away domain or serve the file using ip address. This is to prevent content sniffing errors. Even if you set the content-type, some browsers can be fooled into thinking the document is HTML. This then allows the attacker to insert javascript code that can be executed by the browser.

EDIT :
Some more information on content-type sniffing

Lets say an attacker uploads an XML file that contains HTML in the first few lines. When a user downloads this XML, it is possible to trick the browser into thinking this XML is HTML.

Once you have fooled the browser, an attacker can execute javascript on the users browser. A simple example can be stealing the session cookies.

Putting it together, this is how the attack works - 
1. Attacker uploads XML that has javascript code in it
2. Attacker sends the download link to another user who is the victim
3. Attacker can now execute javascript on the victims browser and steal his cookies

To prevent this - a) Validate the XML per your schema, b) Don't allow the user to download files that were uploaded, c) Serve the file from an ip address or a domain different than your regular domain - so that cookies cannot be stolen. You can read similar information over here - https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8587/how-can-i-be-protected-from-pictures-vulnerabilities

Comment: I second you point in 6. However, even without browsers capable of mime-sniffing, the attacker could upload both an XML file and a XSLT XML stylesheet file transforming anything to malicious HTML. Since both XML and XSLT are downloaded from the same domain, any browser would allow the transformation.

Answer (score 2):

Basic steps:

1. Require the users to have an account and be logged in before allowing them to upload any files
2. Count the number of files they upload each day
3. Don't allow them to upload another file if they have reached the limit.

Other than that, there are TONS of things to think about regarding security of uploading files, but none of the security things has anything to do with uploading only a certain number of files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to identify your users somehow, you generally have two ways:

- using session identifier (stored in the cookie by default). This can be easily bypassed if the user deletes his cookies
- by authenticating your user.

When your user is identified, you can extend your controller action method by business logic to check how many times that user uploaded file. And the rest can be same as the following [article how to upload files in asp.net mvc](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx).

Comment: If you always require an active session, how can deleting the session cookie get around that? The server will just issue a new cookie (starting a new session) if it doesn't get a current session cookie with each request.

Comment: Thats right, but then you have no way how to tell if it is not the same user with new session identifier. Lets say you have anonymous user with session id 1, that user uploads three files (you log that session id 1 uploaded 3 files). Then he deletes his cookies, you start new session with id 2, so he can upload another three files with the session id 2. In another words, you need to identify the users somehow so that they can't get new identity easily.

Comment: Ahh, I understand. I was confused with how you were using the term "identify". I was thinking too narrowly and only considering it would be used to identify the session, and not be used to try and identify the actual user. Inappropriate uses like that don't occur to me very often, but I forget how a new developer may think about things. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

1. Limit the size of the file they can upload (reduces risk of a DDOS on the service)
2. Run it through a validation routine before consuming it (reduces risk of a DDOS on consumption of an invalid file)
3. Require authentication on the upload handler (reduces risk of unwanted files thrown your way)
4. Set a limit on the amount of time an upload can take (this reduces the risk of a DDOS on the service)

Ideally, if you are expecting an xml file of a specific schema, then see if the file presented validates against that schema rather than just as xml, and reject it if it does not.

Just a few to get you started.

Comment: DDOS is just as easy to do with a bunch of small files as it is with a few big ones, and it still hits your server to count the bytes. How does limiting the size or validating the file help against a DDOS attack?

Comment: The size is a good point. You should have a reasonable maxRequestSize (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28VS.80%29.aspx), checking the size when the file is already uploaded doesn't help much in preventing the DOS.